# Which driver package should I download and install?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card, thinkpad

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon x1300 display card in my XP computer.

I have researched some error messages I'm getting and one possible solution points to updating the driver for this card.

When I go to their site, I am informed that this is now a legacy card and I should use the last driver that they provided and am pointed to that location.

When I go there I am presented with two options:

1. Download the Catalyst Software Suite - year 2009
2. Download the GART Driver - year 2004

I suspect that the same driver is contained in both downloads although I don't know enough to be even moderately sure of that.

Which package would you suggest I download, and why?

Comment: Adding the links to the named software would be helpful. As would describing the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATi's [support page](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Legacy/Pages/radeonmob_xp.aspx?type=2.4.2&product=2.4.2.3.8&lang=English) mentions

> AMD has moved to a legacy software
>   support structure for these graphics
>   accelerator products in an effort to
>   better focus development resources on
>   future products.

The list includes the Mobility X1300 & for this, you will need to use ATi Catalyst 9.3 version, since

> All future ATI Catalyst™ releases made
>   available past the ATI Catalyst™ 9.3
>   release will not include support for
>   the legacy products listed above or
>   any of the features associated with
>   those legacy products.